# Does SkyDrive Application should be installed in device in order to connect with skydrive using my application with skydrive sdk (livesdk)?

Tags: android, onedrive

Does SkyDrive Application should be installed in device in order to connect with skydrive using my application with skydrive sdk (livesdk).I had tried tha sample given in sdk zip with my application client id .But it is showing fail toasts like "unable create secure connection", etc.Any valuable suggestions and sample codes are welcomed .Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it worked its not the problem with device or SkyDrive is not Installed and No need of installing SkyDrive App in Android for using in other apps ..It is due to  Mobile Client App is not checked as **Yes** in API Settings of Application Management Page .After selecting it as Yes works perfectly for my app.

[image]